# Django CSRF token missing or incorrect on POST form with FILE Upload

Tags: django, django-forms, csrf-protection, django-csrf

When I submit the form I see this

[image]

which shows that I submit file as well as csrfmiddlewaretoken

However POST Handler shows error message "CSRF token missing or incorrect."

At the same time if I submit the form without files selected - then POST handler doesn't complain on CSRF, it only fails when actual files are selected and submitted into POST handler **model_form_upload**

#### Handler

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'backend/upload.html', {
        'form': form,
        'users':  AppUser.objects.all()
    })
```

#### template

```
{% extends "backend/base.html" %} {% block content %}{% load static %}

<!-- Page Content Holder -->

<h2 class="hline">Example Form With Progress Bar Uploader</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<div class="line"></div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form name="documents"
           id="docs"
           data-toggle="validator"
           class="dropzone"
           role="form"
           enctype="multipart/form-data"
           action=""
           method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputUser"
               class="control-label">User</label><br />
        <select class="selectpicker"
               name="user"
               id="user"
               required>
            <option>Please select a user</option>
            {% for user in users %}
            <option value="{{ user.pk }}">{{ user.username }}</option>
            {% endfor %}}
            </select>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="fileupload"
               type="file"
               name="file"
               multiple />

        <button type="button"
               class="btn btn-primary js-upload-btn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload documents
        </button>
        <br /><br />
        <table id="documents-list"
               class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Documents</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for doc in documents %}
            <tr>
              <td>
                <a href="{{ doc.file.url }}">{{ doc.file.name }}</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>


      <button type="submit">Click me</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade"
       id="modal-progress"
       data-backdrop="static"
       data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Uploading...</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar"
                 role="progressbar"
                 style="width: 0%;">0%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

#### Settings

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # https://opbeat.com/docs/articles/get-started-with-django/#performance-metrics
    'opbeat.contrib.django.middleware.OpbeatAPMMiddleware',
    'libs.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware'
)

# Used to simplify process of doing ajax
# requests through axios
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'XSRF-TOKEN'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_XSRF_TOKEN'

# see doc here
# https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
# Custom headers
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ()
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'x-requested-with',
    'content-type',
    'accept',
    'origin',
    'authorization',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'user-agent',
    'accept-encoding',
    'user-timezone'
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
```

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue?

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue with Django 1.11.17 python 3.7 but only on my local machine. It runs fine in production. Did you figure anything out here?